# How split a string like {200,200}

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split values like `{200,200}` into two strings (`200` and `200`), deleting the comma and brackets.

But when I try to use a standard pattern `^\{*|,|\}*$` I get an error (Illegal escape character) How I can make this split in Java?

```
String[] d = a.split("^\{*|,|\}*$");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, you have to double the escape characters in your regular expressions:

```
String [] data = a.split("^\\{*|,|\\}*$");
```

It is because the regular expression is in a String literal and escape characters already have a meaning in String literals.

Comment: This works perfectly thanks you very much :) !! And thanks to all who answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simpler regular expression:

```
String[] data = a.split("[,{}]");
```

The answer will be in positions `data[1]` and `data[2]`

Answer (score 0):

This should be much faster than split for your particular example:

```
int i = a.indexOf(',');
String s1 = a.substring(1, i);
String s2 = a.substring(i+1, a.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your initial data strings start with `{`, end with `}` and may contain many comma-separated values the split would be as simple as `a.substring(1, a.length()).split(",")`.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem (as another responder [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14782597/20938)) is that you're not escaping the backslashes for use in a Java string literal.

But `split()` is the wrong tool for this job anyway.  It's much easier to perform a normal match and extract the substrings you want via capturing groups:

```
String[] result = new String[2];
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\{(\\d+),(\\d+)\\}$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("{200,200}");
if (m.matches()) {
    result[0] = m.group(1);
    result[1] = m.group(2);
}
```

I know it seems like way too much code for such a simple task, but that's Java for you.